# SQL Alchemy error: MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am building backend application with fastapi and sqlalchemy, and while trying to get a relationship between tables, I am being hit with this error.

full error:

> raise exc.MissingGreenlet(
> sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)

I have stablished other relationships between other tables on the same project the exact same way and had no issues whatsoever up to this point. Since all of the other relationships worked with no issues I can't tell why this one isn't working.

This is what my models for both tables looks like:

```
class ServiceOrderModel(Settings.DB_BASE_MODEL):
    __tablename__ = 'service_order'
    __allow_unmapped__ = True

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    identifier = Column(String(16))
    description = Column(String(256))
    execution_value = Column(Float, nullable=True)
    charged_value = Column(Float, nullable=True)
    status_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('service_status.id'))
    status = relationship('ServiceStatusModel', lazy='joined', back_populates='service_orders')


class ServiceStatusModel(Settings.DB_BASE_MODEL):
    __tablename__ = 'service_status'
    __allow_unmapped__ = True

    id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    status=Column(String(32))
    service_orders=relationship('ServiceOrderModel', back_populates='status', lazy='joined', uselist=True)
```

Can anyone help me spot why is this error happening?

For more context, this is the function that I am trying to use prior to receiving the error:

```
@service_order_router.post('/', status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response_model=ServiceOrderReturnSchema)
async def post(data: ServiceOrderUpdateSchema,db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)) -> Response:

    async with db as database:
        new_service_order = ServiceOrderModel(
            identifier=data.identifier,
            description=data.description,
            execution_value=None,
            charged_value=None,
            status_id=data.status_id,
        )
        database.add(new_service_order)
        await database.commit()

        return new_service_order
```

Comment: I am just trying to post the service order with a status, I will edit the question adding the function that I run once I send the post request.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `status` is probably referenced during rendering the response but isn't loaded during creation because just an id is passed.  Can you try adding this line before returning the service order?

```py
    await database.commit()
    # Force status to load
    await database.refresh(new_service_order, ["status"])
    return new_service_order
```

Comment: That really did it, thanks a lot man